# Visitor module latest version 4.0.2 Bug

Tags: members, zoo-visitor, visitor, eeharbor

I have installed visitor module version 4.0.2 that gives me this error.
[image]

I tried in EE3, EE4 both but get same error everywhere when install module. Any idea?

Comment: Soooo does line 8 on that file look alright? Did you check it out (I don't have that add-on and can't)?

Comment: A typo in code. Well thanks for the help man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, Instead of `<?php echo` it was Typo error `<?phpoecho`. Wonder how can a big agency like EEHarbor can make such mistake and wonder more how can they not answering any emails of support requests. Disappointment here but have to adjust because there is no alternative of Visitors module right now.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I've had some really mixed results in contacting them. Some of our support requests go completely unanswered. We had the best luck with them by asking in the EE Slack channel one time, and happen to get the attention of one of their developers. Don't expect it to change and don't rely on their support, sadly. And honestly? Start factoring out their add-ons wherever possible. The once great default installs (Matrix, etc) are mostly not needed anymore anyways.

Comment: Yah Support was the main reason we get growth in zealousweb.

Comment: My team has navigated and solved a few ridiculous technical bugs in their software without their support (though it was requested). I hope they can change their ways, but for now we have a hiatus on using add-ons for new EE applications.

Comment: Me too. Minimize plugins and upgrade without any tension. haha